# Parsing out same part of JSON object in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a JSON object that looks like the below:

```
{u'data': [{u'time': 1422000000, u'value': u'3.4622110423016'},
           {u'time': 1422086400, u'value': u'2.2860814710007'},
           {u'time': 1422172800, u'value': u'3.2759128386337'},
           {u'time': 1422259200, u'value': u'3.1275526348711'},
           {u'time': 1422345600, u'value': u'5.0558305332819'},
           {u'time': 1422432000, u'value': u'3.6486900025894'},
           {u'time': 1422518400, u'value': u'5.1073740942857'}]}
```

How can I parse all of the values to a list?  I tried the below, but neither worked:

```
seven_day_spam_data["data"][0]["value"][:]
seven_day_spam_data["data"][0]["value"][0:7]
```

I would like the list to look like this:

```
[3.4622110423016,
2.2860814710007,
3.2759128386337,
3.1275526348711,
5.0558305332819,
3.6486900025894,
5.1073740942857]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
out = [d["value"] for d in seven_day_spam_data["data"]]
```

The reason your approach isn't working is that `seven_day_spam_data["data"][0]` doesn't correspond to a list of all your values, it just corresponds to the first of seven dictionaries within `"data": [...]` (denoted by the `[0]` in your code).  To get the value of `"value"` from each of those dictionaries, you need to iterate over the dictionaries, which the list comprehension does.

If you have control over the JSON data, you might consider storing it in a simpler way.  For example:

```
data = {
    "time": [1, 2, 3],
    "values": [3.2, 3.4, 3.3]
}
```

Then you could get the values using `data["values"]`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Unfortunately, I do not have control over the JSON output.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see that under the key `data`, you have a list and the list consists of n dictionaries all having 2 key- value pairs, so you can create an empty list first to store the data as `final_list = []` then you can iterate over all the dictionaries under the data key as `for sample_dict in seven_day_spam_data['data']` and then you can extract the value field from each dictionary and append it to the final list as `final_list.append(sample_dict['value'])`. So combining all those small fragments we get this code :

```
final_list = []
for sample_dict in seven_day_spam_data['data']:
    final_list.append(sample_dict['value'])
```